# MXML composite container initialization error

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I'm getting an odd error from my composite canvas component:

```
 An ActionScript error has occurred:
  Error: null
at mx.core::Container/initialize()[C:\autobuild\galaga\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\Container.as:2560]
at -REMOVED THIS FOR STACK OVERFLOW-.view::EditableCanvas/initialize()[.../view/EditableCanvas
    ....
```

It seems to be related to the fact that my composite component has a child and I'm trying to add one in the place I'm using the component. So how can I do this correctly?

Component code looks like this (EditableCanvas.mxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Script>
<mx:Image id="editTextImage"
            source="@Embed('/../assets/icons/small/edit.png')"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

The code that is using the code looks like this:

```
<view:EditableCanvas
            width="290" 
            height="120" 
            backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" 
            horizontalScrollPolicy="off" 
            borderStyle="solid" 
            cornerRadius="3">
            <mx:Text id="textContentBox" width="270" fontFamily="nautics" fontSize="12" text="{_text}"/>
</view:EditableCanvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution all by my own from [Adobe Flex 3 Help](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=mxmlcomponents_2.html):

> If you include child tags of the root container tag in an MXML component file, you cannot add child tags when you use the component as a custom tag in another MXML file. If you define an empty container in an MXML file, you can add child tags when you use the component as a custom tag.

The way to have child elements in a composite component (that also accepts childs from custom tag) is to add them after creationComplete in as3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not binding to the init() function, and instead just having creationComplete="init()" ?